# Update XML attributes

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

I have created a function to update some attributes in XML but if index is 0 the update is ok, but if is more than 0, **The index being passed is out of range** occurs.

```
    public void updateAtributexml(string value, int index)
    {
        string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string file = "settings.xml";
        string specificFolder = Path.Combine(folder, "DesktopCleaner");

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        xmlDoc.Load(specificFolder + "\\" + file);

        XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("DesktopCleaner/Settings/Setting");
        node.Attributes[index].Value = value;

        xmlDoc.Save(specificFolder + "\\" + file);

    }
```

My xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DesktopCleaner>
  <Settings>
    <Setting updateChecker="1" />
    <Setting desktopFolder="0" />
    <Setting downloadsFolder="0" />
    <Setting customFolder="0" />
  </Settings>
</DesktopCleaner>
```

Comment: Non of your elements contains more than 1 attribute, so it's logical that their index is 0. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The error says it all. "The index being passed is out of range". There is only 1 attribute. Passing in 0 accesses that attribute. Passing in a higher number is out of the range.

Comment: So how can I set value to the rest of Setting?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it's *always* selecting the first `Setting` element:

```
<Setting updateChecker="1" />
```

This element has only one attribute, thus if index is greater than 0 you get an error.

So, instead of:

```
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("DesktopCleaner/Settings/Setting");
node.Attributes[index].Value = value;
```

Use:

```
 XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("DesktopCleaner/Settings");
 node.ChildNodes[index].Attributes[0].Value = value;
```

Comment: I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I call the function: `updateAtributexml("1", 1);` and even if I whant to `MessageBox.Show(node.ChildNodes[1].Attributes[0].Value);` I get same error.

Comment: @Sebastian The only case when I get this error is when `index` is greater than 3. You have to include a check on the number of `Setting` nodes in your code as well.

Comment: @Sebastian Have you subtituted the node assignment statement as well (i.e. `node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("DesktopCleaner/Settings");`)

Comment: `node.ChildNodes.Count.ToString()` returns 0, very weird.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68844/discussion-between-giorgos-betsos-and-sebastian-corneliu-virlan).

Answer (score 0):

Each of your Setting nodes only has a single attribute, so 0 is the only valid index.